# Taxonomy: allow "All values" choice, visible as "All values" in results

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I'm looking for an "All values" choice in a taxonomy vocabulary. 
It is about mobility regions, and some "contents" might be able to be tagged as "All regions". That is coming up new in the project and I already set up a taxonomy vocabulary before to categorize by regions. 
Is there any simple way to do this? 
In the results list, it should be refered at "All regions", and not region 1 - region 2 - etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck the **Required** option from exposed form field settings. Then there will be one more option **- Any -** will appear in filter dropdown. It will work same as **All values**.

You can also change **- Any -** value in to **All Values** by using **hook_form_alter**.

****EDIT :****

So the good structure is : 
- Create a taxonomy vocabulary for the values ;
- Create a level 1 with an "All values" term ; 
- Create a level 2 with all individual values ; 
- Add the taxonomy relationship in the views and load the field taxonomy terms for each result ; 
- Add the taxonomy as an exposed filter **with depth** ; 
- In the **settings of this filter, define a depth of -1**, so every individual value chosen will also return the parent value. 
As an example, a chosen region (as a taxonomy term) will return content indexed for "all regions" parent term.

Comment: thanks but it is not a required field and the required option in the exposed filter is uncheck. Currently the "none" option works like "all" in filtering, but the idea is that the contents which would be determined as "all values" (all regions in that case) in the interface using the regions vocabulary, have to respond to any choice of region made in the exposed filter, and display in the region field : "All regions".

Comment: You have added "All regions" as a term in your vocabulary? or you just want to show "All regions" instead of showing "none" in exposed filter?

Comment: nope. It would be a lead if there was a way to make any other choice of individual region in the exposed form display contents with the term All regions only.

Comment: Ok maybe if I put this on 2 levels, with all regions in level 1 and the individuals in level 2. Checking the choice like required, so by default, the choice will be all regions. And I can maybe determine all regions as a choice in the interface... I'll try this to see